# What is the proper behaviour for a Paxos agent in this scenario?

Tags: algorithm, distributed, consensus, paxos

I'm looking into Paxos and I'm confused about how the algorithm should behave in this contrived example. I hope the diagram below explains the scenario.

[image]

A few points:

- Each agent acts as a proposer/acceptor/learner
- Prepare messages have form `(instance, proposal_num)`
- Propose messages have form `(instance, proposal_num, proposal_val)`
- Server1 and Server2 both decide to start the proposal process at the same time
- In the beginning messages M1, M2 and M3 occur simultaneously

It seems here that although the protocol is 'correct', i.e. only one value `S2` is chosen, Server1 and Server2 believe that it was chosen because of different proposal numbers.

Does the Paxos algorithm only terminate when the `Decide(...)` message is sent out to the learners? I must be misunderstanding *Paxos Made Simple* but I thought the choice was made the moment the proposers achieved quorum for their `Propose(...)` messages.

If the choice is only made after the `Decide(...)` message is sent out to the agents, should Server2 terminate its sending of `Decide(1, 5, S2)` when it recovers because it saw a later `Prepare(1, 7)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just gonna redefine the terms (let's also throw out the 1 because we're only examining one Paxos iteration):

1) Propose(n) == propose(n), message from a proposer with current identity n

2) AcceptPrepare(n,v) == ack(n,v), message sent to proposer n. v is blank if this node hasn't accepted any value yet, o.w. v equals the value it has accepted

3) CreateDecide(n,v) == accept!(x,v), asking the nodes to accept this value from proposer with identity x. nodes will reject the message if they've ack'ed a prepare(n) message where n > x

Once quorum is achieved for prepare(n) -- that is, a majority have ack'ed the message -- then the proposer with identity n sends out a command accept!(n,v). If a prepare(n+x), x > 0, was sent out by a proposer with identity n+x -- and it's ack'ed by a majority -- between the ack(n,v) messages and the accept!(n,v), then a majority has promised not to accept values proposed with a timestamp < n+x, x > 0 (AKA the nodes will reject the accept!(n,v))

The choice is made as soon as a majority receives an accept!(n,v) message which they have not promised to ignore.

Thus, when server2 comes back online and it sends accept!(5,S2), it will be ignored because 5 < 7.

Comment: It has been a while :) I accepted your answer because of the phrase "the choice is made as soon as a majority receives an accept!(n, v) message which they have not promised to ignore". That's key.

The Paxos protocol is 'complete' as soon as a majority of acceptors accept a value. The Commit (or Decide) is simply an optimization in which a distinguished learner (i.e. the proposer) broadcasts the consensus to all interested learners. You could do skip the Commit by having each Acceptor broadcast their vote to all learners. This is stated in "Paxos Made Simple", though it's easy to overlook.

Comment: @dougvk "timestamp"? there are no timestamps in Paxos do you mean ballot number?

Answer (score 0):

To give a counterpoint to the accepted answer, the algorithm itself never really needs to *terminate* in any terribly well-defined sense. It makes more sense to talk about each node individually terminating its participation in the algorithm, which is implementation-defined. Then perhaps you could say that the algorithm itself has terminated when all the participating nodes have dropped out, if that were a useful thing to want to know.

The algorithm has effectively *converged* as soon as a majority of acceptors have sent their `AcceptPropose` messages for the same ballot (in the sense that once that has happened there is no option about what value may ultimately be decided) but this is not a state of affairs that can be observed in practice: for instance if the network were to start dropping messages just before this set of `AcceptPropose` messages were sent, no node would be able to learn that the algorithm had converged until connectivity were restored.

However, once *one* node knows that the algorithm has converged (by having received `AcceptPropose` messages from a majority) it is safe for it to share the chosen value via conventional means, e.g. by sending a `Decide` message by broadcast or gossip, and for other nodes to forward it on until every node knows that convergence was achieved.

Each node can terminate its participation in the algorithm once it knows the value to which the algorithm has converged, although it may prefer to keep participating for longer, depending on your implementation constraints.

You have to think a bit about failure-tolerance to convince yourself that terminate-on-decided preserves liveness: if all the nodes that know what value was decided were to die before they could share it, would progress still be possible? The answer is, fortunately, yes: as long as a majority of nodes remains alive, if any of them knows the decided value then it can share it with the others, and if not then there's a majority of participating nodes that just need to pick a higher ballot number and run another round.

---

One thing to be careful of in the accepted answer is this phrase:

> The choice is made as soon as a majority receives an accept!(n,v) message which they have not promised to ignore.

Firstly, there's nothing in the protocol about *promising to ignore* `AcceptPropose` messages. Promises pertain to which `Propose` messsages should be ignored/rejected. A majority of `AcceptPropose` messages can *always* be used to learn the chosen value, regardless of the ballot number.

Secondly, the choice is effectively made as soon as a majority *sends* `AcceptPropose` messages. You can't observe this directly so you have to wait until at least one node has received `AcceptPropose` messages from a majority before knowing that the choice has been made. Once that's happened, you can share the chosen value via more `AcceptPropose` messages or via a broadcast/gossip of `Decided` messages, depending on which suits your implementation constraints better.

Comment: reading the accepted answer I am not seeing the statement that you are warning about "promising to ignore AcceptPropose" as it is talking about having made a promise higher than the CreateDecide (aka accept!)?

Comment: The block quote in my answer is taken verbatim from the accepted answer.

Comment: yes but your next line equates "AcceptPropse" with "accept!" when he states in is (3) that its CreateDecide. so I am thinking thats a typo on your part. then I read his block statement as "a majority accepted a value where they had not made a higher promise" which is paxos so i am struggling to see what he is saying which is wrong and I am struggling to comprehend your warning.

Comment: That's a good point. The way that the terms are redefined in that answer don't tie in with the rest of the text: if `accept!(n,v)` is sent after quorum is achieved on `prepare(n)` then `accept!(n,v)` is `AcceptPropose` not `CreateDecide`. Still, there's nothing in the protocol about promising to ignore `CreateDecide` messages either. The only messages you promise to ignore are the `prepare(n)` ones.